# Combine ASP.NET MVC (without Entity Framework) project with another Entity Framework-based project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Currently, I have one project which is developed using ASP.NET MVC WITHOUT Entity Framework (EF) and I am using the full .NET Framework instead of .NET Core.

Now I have another new application that I need to develop under the same project. But I would like to use Entity Framework for this application.

Is that possible for me to combine EF and non EF under one project?

And what is the thing that I need to know/beware of?

I tried to search online but I couldn't get an answer for this.

I hope someone from here can help and give me some advice.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean 2 projects in 1 solution?

Answer (score 1):

combine EF and non EF under one project?

Did you mean under one solution? If so, you can add another project as you did for previous one with EF nuget packages. Inside the same solution add another class library project for your Entity Framework modeling and tasks. Add the reference of this library to your new project and you are ready to use EF in your newly created project.

You can use this library in the existing project to use EF as well (if you want).

NB: This answer may divert your thoughts as I am not fully sure about your scenario. If so, please describe your situation in a broad sense.

Comment: Alright. I will try your suggestion... Thanks for your help. Appreciate!